# How can I add a title suffix in ASP.NET (Web Forms)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, title

I'm trying to add a title suffix = eg " - MySite" to all page titles, but I want to add this in a central location - not manually on each of the pages. How can I do this, as if you have head runat="server" you pretty much lose all control over how this gets rendered.

Currently the titles are set in the Page directive (with the  element set to  runat="server").

Comment: Are you using a Master Page?

Comment: Either you change all the page directive titles in Visual Studio (CTRL+SHIFT+H, then use a Regular expression to search and replace), or you'll have to resort to a Javascript hack, which is considered poor practice. You could also change the title in the Page Load event of a master page, but that would be incurring an overload you really don't need to solve a problem you could handle otherwise.

Comment: No I'm using standard Web Forms.

Comment: @Renan - you can't use JavaScript to change a page title as it will only change it client side (ie crawlers won't see it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be done with custom PageAdapter. Does not require master pages or editing all page files:

Add adapter class to web project:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.Adapters;

namespace SampleWebApplication
{
    public class PageTitleAdapter : PageAdapter
    {
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

            if (this.Page.Title != null)
            {
               this.Page.Title = "Somesite - " + this.Page.Title;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right Click on ASP.NET Project/Add/Add ASP.NET Folder, choose App_Browsers.

Add/New Browser File named BrowserFile.browser to that folder.

Edit the file to specify adapter class:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
        <controlAdapters>
            <adapter
              controlType="System.Web.UI.Page"
              adapterType="SampleWebApplication.PageTitleAdapter">
            </adapter>
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: Brilliant - that's exactly what I was after. Thanks very much!

Comment: Actually having tried it it doesn't always seem to work. If the title was set programmatically, then this code seems to run too early and doesn't take effect. I've tried moving it to OnLoad and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Aha - changing it to OnPreRender() works :)  I've edited the answer accordingly... Seems to need a null check too as the event seems to fire twice - once where Page.Title is null and a second time where it's been set.

Answer (score 2):

The way i accomplished this was to have all my pages inherit from a base class. In the base class i override the OnPreLoad event and set the page title. This gave me much more control and allowed me to change the pages dynamically. So in my config file i set the default page title "My Site" then on in the code behind page of each page i override OnPreInit with the active pageTitle

Web.Config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
        <add key="defaultWebPageTitle" value="My Site"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Baseclass

```
public class BaseWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private string _activePageTitle = string.Empty;

protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    string defaultPageTitle = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["defaultWebPageTitle"];
    //Load the theme and masterpage.
    base.OnPreInit(e);

    Page.Title = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_activePageTitle) ? characterReplace(_activePageTitle)    + " | " + defaultPageTitle : defaultPageTitle);
    }
    public string ActivePageTitle
    {
        get
        { return _activePageTitle; }
        set
        { _activePageTitle = value; }
    }
}
```

Random Financing Page

```
public partial class Financing : BaseWebForm
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivePageTitle = "Financing";
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted as this works for smaller solutions, but I'm going with @PashaPash's solution as it doesn't involve editing my 101 aspx files :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [Master Page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages) to consolidate common layout to a single location.

Failing that, if the title is being set in the `@Page` directive then you *probably* can affect it site-wide with a little code.  Essentially you'd want to create a `class` which inherits from `Page`, then have all of your page classes inherit from your new custom class.  (Yes, you wanted to avoid making a change in many places.  But since this *exists* in many places already, that's kind of a foregone conclusion.)

[The `Page` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) has [a `Title` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.title.aspx) which you can then override in your class.  Well, probably more appropriately, override a page event which can *set* the title.  Something like:

```
public class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.Title = this.Title + " - MySite";
    }
}
```

That way any page which inherits from this class will execute this `OnLoad` method when the page loads.

Comment: It's not a master page site and changing a non master page site to use master pages would be weeks of work given it has several hundred pages.

Comment: Apologies! Must admit that once I saw the first line I presumed the rest of your post was relating to using master pages :)

Comment: @NickG: To be fair, Master Pages *are* the "correct" way to do this.  I realize it would take effort to convert to that paradigm, but if these challenges are going to continue then it sounds like effort well-spent.

Comment: This is a website I have been developing since ASP.NET 1.0 beta and is a decade old! The sheer number of aspx pages and legacy code makes any upgrade very impractical :( Fundamentally, the customer would not want to pay us to do it. All new pages I create are now based on a Master Page, but I've come to the conclusion that upgrading the old ones to Master Pages just isn't the best use of my customer's money.

Comment: @NickG: A very fair conclusion, as long as the numbers match up on the cost/benefit analysis.  Upgrading for the sake of upgrading always sounds fun (developers *hate* legacy code and *love* re-writing things), but as you say the value needs to be demonstrable.

Comment: ..and forgive me if I sound frustrated, but I would LOVE to convert them to master pages and have spent hours looking into the practicality of doing so, but despite obviously being better for any *new* project, there is very little practical advantage to be gained in converting existing pages which already work :)

Comment: @NickG: Well, for any *new* project I'd recommend ditching WebForms altogether for MVC (or any MV*-based framework). People love to point out that the demise of WebForms has been greatly exaggerated, but the strategic indications from Microsoft at every level point to a long-term plan of deprecating forms architecture in general, web or otherwise. The WinRT paradigm (which they really want people to adopt, but so far with no success) has no support for forms architecture... the first time they've *ever* done that since, well, DOS. Forms has a visible end of life on the horizon, MV* does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid the overload of renaming on every load, and want to hard code the suffix in Visual Studio:

- Press **CTRL+SHIFT+H** to open the *find and replace* dialog;
- For searching, use the expression `(<@Page.+Title=\"[^"]*){1}` (may require some adjustments depending on the version you are using);
- For replacement, use the expression `$1 - MySite`.

Comment: Renaming a page isn't really much of an "overload" though.  In a quick and dirty test, it seems you can do this 10,000 times per page view with no noticeable change in page load time. Try it :)

Comment: @NickG true and +1 to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an ASP.NET website, you could create a class in your project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Nickspace {

  public class Tools {
    public static string SetTitle(string title) {
      return title + " - MySite";
    }
  }

}
```

That is very crude, but then you could use that in your ASP.NET pages using inline code:

```
<%@ Language=C# %>
<html>
  <head><title><%=Nickspace.Tools.SetTitle("Page1") %></title></head>
  <body>
    Blah-Blah-Blah
    <br/>
    This would be easier if I had a Master Page file.
  </body>
</html>
```

That code is untested, of course.